# jquery and jscript if else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the code below to make a box appear when certain text is clicked. How do i limit it so only one box can be slid down at a time.

E.g. if i click the first button it slides down, then if i click the second button the first box slides up again?

Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip1").click(function(){
    $(".panel1").slideDown("fast");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip2").click(function(){
    $(".panel2").slideDown("fast");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip3").click(function(){
    $(".panel3").slideDown("fast");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip4").click(function(){
    $(".panel4").slideDown("fast");
  });
});
</script>



<div id="betslip">
                <td><div class="panel1"><?php echo $bet1; ?></div></td>
                <td><div class="panel2"><?php echo $bet2; ?></div></td>
                <td><div class="panel3"><?php echo $bet3; ?></div></td>
                <td><div class="panel4"><?php echo $bet4; ?></div></td>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor and minimize your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[class=^'flip'").click(function(){
    // get panel class
    var panelClass = this.className.replace('flip', 'panel');
    // hide all open
    $("[class^='panel']").hide();
    // show current one now
    $('.' + panelClass).slideDown('fast');
  });
});
```

***That's all you need.***

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could probably start by adding in some code to `.slideUp()` each of the other panels. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: i've added the slideUp but soon as it slides down it slides up straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Give all the flips a common class name:`flip`:

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
    $('.panel').slideUp('fast'):
});
```

This will SlideUp all the panels, then slide down with the functions you have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip1").click(function(){
    $(".panel1").slideDown("fast");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip2").click(function(){
    $(".panel2").slideDown("fast");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip3").click(function(){
    $(".panel3").slideDown("fast");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip4").click(function(){
    $(".panel4").slideDown("fast");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip1").click(function(){
        $("div[class^=panel]").slideup();
        $(".panel1").slideDown("fast");
    });

    $(".flip2").click(function(){
        $("div[class^=panel]").slideup();
        $(".panel1").slideDown("fast");
    });

    // Do the rest
});
```

Use just one `document.ready()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[class^="flip"]').click(function(){
      var thisId = $(this).attr('class').replace('flip');
      $('[class^="panel"]').slideUp("fast");
      $('.panel'+thisId).slideDown("fast");
  });
});
```

Note that this would only work if you have only one class assigned for `.panel` and `.flip` elements

Comment: I think you mean *only one class* instead of *more than one class*.